# Is there a way to automatically refresh an Excel file using ODBC connection (via python or CMD)?

Tags: python, odbc, ibm-midrange

There's this one **`.xlsm` file** that i need to refresh, automatically, on a regular basis, with data taken from an **AS400 device**.

The AS400 device launches a script every N. hours; said script updates a file, which contains the data we need to get to the .xlsm file. When called, Excel's "*Refresh All*" function creates an ODBC connection with AS400 and populates the .xlsm file with its data.

At the moment, the refreshing process is **only manual**, and consists of:

- opening the file with MS Excel (I'm using Office 365's version, if it can somehow help)
- clicking on "*Refresh All*" (which opens a [dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpbg8.png) asking to insert ODBS credentials)
- Logging in with AS400 credentials

Doing so, file is updated, but of course it would be much more efficient to have it done automatically.

Is there a way to have a python script connected to ODBC (using libraries like `pywin32` or similars), and use said connection to refresh the file without a human input? Or is there a way to bypass the whole refresh thing to do it without inserting the credentials inside the dialog window?

Comment: Don't know about Python.  But you can do this using PHP on the AS400.   Write a web service in PHP that uses the db2 functions to read the data from the AS400. Then the PHPExcel package to create the excel file.  Finally, use the HTTP_POST SQL function on the AS400 to call the PHP web service when you want to create the excel file.

Comment: @RockBoro thank you, that's a good alternative if the python thing doesn't go well!

Comment: If PHPExcel is an acceptable alternative, then you might as well stick with Python. [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) started life as a Python port of PHPExcel, and has become the leading all-purpose Excel package for Python. ([XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) is arguably better for creating workbooks from scratch, but it doesn't read or update existing workbooks.)

Comment: Also, PHPExcel has been unmaintained for years now (officially deprecated in 2017 and archived in 2019). It does have a successor, [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

Comment: @JohnY i already used PhpSpreadsheet for another project and it works quite well, even thought what i did was a pretty simple script. My objective, since the script is written almost entirely in Python, was to have this section operating in python too without implementing other languages, but for sure that's absolutely a good alternative, in case what i'm trying to do right now doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a solution, although it's not exactly the best solution since it has its limitation, but beside that it works quite well.

Inside the Excel file, I went to the "Connections" tab, opened the affected connection's Properties>Usage tab and checked the "**Refresh data when opening the file**" option; then, on the Properties>Definition tab I also checked the "**Save password**" option.

> **Note that this could be quite a vulnerability if the machine is accessed by many people and you don't want your data to be seen**, but
> this wasn't my case since the machine isn't accessible to unauthorized users.

Inside a BAT file, i wrote this script:

```
START excel.exe "path\to\file.xlsm"
timeout 10
python "[path]\save_refreshed_file.py"
```

What this BAT does is basically, opening the file (so that the connecions update themselves automatically) and calling to a python script that does this:

```
import xlwings as xw

def saveRefreshedFile():

    wbk = xw.Book("path\to\file.xlsm")

    wbk.save("path\to\file.xlsm")

    wbk.close()
```

Basically, after the file is opened (and consequently updated) by the BAT, the python script connects to the Excel Workbook via the xlwings library and saves it.

After all this is executed, the file is correctly updated even if there's not someone that can open the file manually. To have it executed on a regular data, the batch can be put under a Task Scheduler.

It's kind of a bypass of what I had in mind to solve the problem when I first asked the question a couple months ago, but it worked quite well for me, so here it is. Hope it helps someone else too.